# Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation marks after the character string ')'

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a website using asp.net and inbuilt database and I'm trying to solve this error for 2 hours now. I'm using string concatenation in my query.
 Raw query : 
          insert into Account holder values('Yash','Gadhvi','MJShinichi','Who is your favorite actor/Actress?','Yui Aragaki');

```
      String MyCommand = "insert into AccountHolder values('  "+FNameBox.Text+"  ','  "+LNameBox.Text+"  ','  "+UName.Text+"  ','  "+PassMe.Text+"  ','  "+Qs.Text+"  ','  "+As.Text+"  ')";
    SqlCommand adder = new SqlCommand(MyCommand,sqlcon);
    sqlcon.Open();
    int exe = adder.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlcon.Close();
```

Can't use parameterized query because there is no procedure, other than that I've tried literally everything (blank spaces between ' and " are to separate single and double quotations). I've searched around on the internet but it didn't help much.... The best what it gave me was compilation error.

Comment: You really should use a parameterized query.  This aside, can you print your raw insert statement and include this in your question?

Comment: Yes you can and should use parameratized queries.

Comment: I tried to manually insert data into table and it worked.    insert into Account holder values('Yash','Gadhvi','MJShinichi','Who is your favorite actor/Actress?','Yui Aragaki');

Comment: How can I use parameterized query in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code for this:

```
String MyCommand = "insert into AccountHolder values(@FNameBox, @LNameBox, @UName, @PassMe, @Qs, @As)";
SqlCommand adder = new SqlCommand(MyCommand, sqlcon);
adder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNameBox", FNameBox.Text);
adder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNameBox", LNameBox.Text);
adder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", UName.Text);
adder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassMe", PassMe.Text);
adder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qs", Qs.Text);
adder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@As", As.Text);   
sqlcon.Open();
int exe = adder.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcon.Close();
```

If you insist continue the insert without parameters, check your data you probably have a '  inside the data.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the example.

Comment: No sadly, it's still there, it still shows errr. Do i need to include a header file or something?

Comment: Compilation error message : 'string' doesn't contain a definition for "Parameters" and no extension method "Parameters" accepting a first arguement of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using diretive or an assembly reference?) Line 22: MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName",FNameBox.Text);

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the name of your variables have confused me :) I have fixed it again.